# Extensions in Magento 2 in Plesk 12 via APS Package

Tags: extensions, magento-2.1

after a while of trying to run magento2 on plesk 12 manually I decided to try the APS package and installed Magento 2 as an application on my domain. Everything seems to work almost fine, but I cannot get any extemsions to be installed. Whenever I try to install an extension, my server crashes and I have to reinstall the whole application. When installing vie Setup Wizard, it is stuck at "Update pending" and a manual installation via console leads to the server being not reachable (HTTP Error 500). What can I do to install extensions properly? One interesting find: when I copy the code files and change the config.php to include the extension (in this case a language pack), the server is unreachable as well, but after revoking the changes in config.php, the language pack worked (withoit officially being active). Unfortunately this does not work for other extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by installing manually and setting file permissions to 777 to var and pub dirs.